# Struts 2: Send a JSON string with JQuery ajax submit to be mapped into a List of complextypes

Tags: java, json, jquery, struts2

If a struts 2 action class have a property of

`List<User> userList`.

And the user class has properties like

`username, password, createdDate` etc.

Is it possible to make struts populate the list by passing the appropriate JSON string, while submitting a jQuery ajax request pointed at that action.

If it is possible how? Specially how will the JSON string have to look like?

Please ask any clarifications.

EDIT : I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. What I want to do is not get data from Action to a JSP, or submit a form to populate the data. I want to submit a AJAX request with JSON data which Struts 2 can use to automatically populate the List in the Action class.

Not submit the form with AJAX.

Comment: you mean u want a GET request?

Comment: Nope. I want to do an jQuery ajax submit with the data generated that will be converted to the Java List by Struts 2.

Comment: and Jquery will send data in JSON format and you want S2 to convert that JSON to java list? m i correct?

Comment: i believe this can be done with the help of S2 json plugin as it does the work for you.S2 Json plugin do JSON to java object and other way around mapping.have you tried that?

Comment: That's from the Java side right? For script side..

Comment: I just read up on it. I was under the impression that struts 2 has it bundled....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. you should define your action result `type="json"` and check you have json plugin on your classpath, make sure you have

   ```
   <struts>
       <package name="your_package" extends="struts-default, json default" namespace="/">
       // your action here
       </pacakge>
       ...
   </struts>
   ```
2. edit your action class like this

   ```
   public class myAction extends ActionSupport {
       private List<User> userlist; // getter and setter
       public String execute() {
          // your moves
          return SUCCESS;
       }
   }
   ```
3. then you can do some on your jsp page to show the result like:

   ```
   <s:iterator list="userList">
     <s:property value="username"/>
     <s:property value="password"/>
     <s:property value="createdDate"/>
   <s:iterator>
   ```

I hope this can help you..

**UPDATE**

if you have already a json object:

```
{
   "userList" : [
      {"username" : "username", "password" : "afgasdfa", "createdDate" : "date-in-format"},
      {"username" : "username", "password" : "afgasdfa", "createdDate" : "date-in-format"},
      {"username" : "username", "password" : "afgasdfa", "createdDate" : "date-in-format"},
      {"username" : "username", "password" : "afgasdfa", "createdDate" : "date-in-format"}
   ]
}
```

this should be the format.

then you should get this object from your action class with `List<User> userList`

just try it and feedback.

**UPDATE 2**

maybe you should get your json object using `String`, then convert it to Java Object using:

```
String stringObject; // which get your string from http
List<User> userList;

userList = (List<User>)JSON.deserialize(stringObject,List<User>.class);
```

Please feedback again.

Comment: Please see my edit. I want to do the opposite of this with dynamically generated JSON. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Nope the struts property is still null. I wonder if there's any struts configuration I need to make...

Comment: Hi, you do need include `json-default` and which verson of struts2 are you using?

Comment: your package, which includes your action should extends `json-default`, struts2 2.1.6 have not integrated json plugin, you should include it by yourself on the classpath

Comment: I'm having trouble with a conflict when adding that jar. This is going to have to go to the back-burner for a bit. I'll post what I did in a day or two.

Comment: please check, if all of your struts2 plugin in the same version. it is kind of important.

Comment: I already got this jsonplugin-0.33.jar in classpath. When I add struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar the problems come while deploying.