# How to send JSON data from JSP page to action class in Struts2 using AJAX

Tags: json, jquery, struts2

I want to transfer json data from jsp page to action class using ajax in jquery.
Following is the jquery code.

```
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : contextPath+"/postData.action",   
async: false ,
data :json,
dataType:"json", 
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
contentType: "application/json",
success : function(result) {
    }
});
```

Follwing is the Action Class Code:

```
private String data;

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public String execute() 
{
    System.out.println(data);
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

Struts.xml config  file

```
<action name="postData" class="demo.StoreJSONData" >     
    <result name="success">/jsp/output.jsp</result>

 </action>
```

Code of sample json code:

```
{
"rectangle": {
    "0": {
        "id": "rectangle_1",
        "displayData": "<div class=\"\" style=\"background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 389px; height: 129px; position: absolute; left: 92px; top: 360px; border: 1px solid black; z-index: 4;\" id=\"rectangle_1\"></div>"
    }
},
"eclipse": {
    "0": {
        "id": "eclipse_1",
        "displayData": "<div class=\"\" style=\"position: absolute; z-index: 5; background-color: rgb(243, 239, 15); border: 1px solid black; width: 245px; height: 83px; border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%; left: 563px; top: 445px;\" id=\"eclipse_1\"></div>"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please post some code that you have tried !!

Comment: I have added code into question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action to accept dynamic json data from user interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749885/action-to-accept-dynamic-json-data-from-user-interface)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want and what data you want to send to your Struts2 action.
here is the way to send JSON data using Jquery to Struts2 action

### JQuery

```
var arr = { value1: 'value1', value2: 'value2'}; // any size data

$.ajax({
    url: 'action URL',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

- `JSON.stringify` method will convert java-script object into a JSON string ,most of current browser provide this method Out of box but for old one you might need other way like json2.js etc.

Struts2 already provide a plugin to handle JSON data in and out for you, have a look at [json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html) to get more details about it.

Please keep following points in mind

- You should define your action `result type="json"` and check you have json plugin on your classpath, make sure you have.

Please have look at following question which will give you more detailed idea

- [struts-2-send-a-json-string-with-jquery-ajax-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429828/struts-2-send-a-json-string-with-jquery-ajax-submit-to-be-mapped-into-a-list-of)
- [json-jquery-to-struts2-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746051/json-jquery-to-struts2-action?rq=1)

Comment: i have looked into given link, i have added code in question. Can you suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use more high level plugin (struts-jquery-plugin).
It has Ajax call support which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not agree with you, struts2-Jquery plugin provide other functionalists and though plugin is really good but if you do not want to use there tags, there is no need to add any extra dependency.

Comment: Yes. The plugin provides UI Components (Tree, Tab, Grid, AutoCompleter, Progress bar ...) which may not be suitable all projects. Also there are Ajax components for links, div and forms which will be very useful.
If your project is fully based on AJAX I suggest you use this ( or similar) components.

Answer (score 0):

Hey The problem is you are directly posting array of objects. So Struts2 don't know whicch method to call. Change your json data like below. Then it will work.

```
{"data":[{"id":"1","code":"111","name":"ddd"},
"id":"2","code":"222","name":"sss"},
{"id":"3","code":"333","name":"eee"}]}
```

Then inside the setter read with object

```
public void setData(List < Report > data) {
System.out.println("Setter Call Flow");
this.data = data;
```

}

Where Report is a java class contains id,code,name as it's members with setters and getters.