# sending ajax call to server with json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am new to "jQuery ajax",I am sending the request to the server using ajax. I am sending the data ie no, name, class, age as normal parameters. My Requirement is , I want to send the data in JSON format. My code is,

```
function fun1() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        jsonp: null,
        jsonpCallback: null
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'register.action',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            no: document.getElementById("id1").value,
            name: document.getElementById("id2").value,
            clas: document.getElementById("id3").value,
            age: document.getElementById("id4").value    
        },    
        success: function (data) {    
            printStudentDetails(data);    
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}
```

My server side resource is java.

Comment: And what is your question / problem?

Comment: You should probably use POST to send json data - I'm not even sure what GET will do to your data.  E.g., it may just encode: ?no=JUNK&name=JUNK.  Also, add `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: Look at this question for example.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323338/jquery-ajax-posting-json-to-webservice

Comment: Check out Java JSONObject json.org/java I assume you want to render a java object as json

Comment: As Blazes says: change to `type: 'post'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    jsonp: null,
    jsonpCallback: null
});

function fun1(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'register.action',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            jsonData: JSON.stringify({
                no: $('#id1').val(),
                name: $('#id2').val(),
                clas: $('#id3').val(),
                age: $('#id4').val()
            }) 
        },    
        success: function (data) {    
            printStudentDetails(data);    
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });

}
```

this will make a HTTP post to your server url and one of the post field will be called "jsonData" which will contain json encoded string value of your form data (which you can decode into array/object for manipulation/storage in your server).

Comment: how can i decode this json encoded string value at the server side.I am using java struts2 at the server side.

Comment: I don't use java, i answered the jquery/ajax potion of your question. Did a search on google and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11430777/2332336). You need to define in your java a class defintion of what your JSON data contains and decode back to data using this (EXAMPLE): `List<User> userList = (List<User>)JSON.deserialize(stringObject,List<User>.class);` where "User" is the class defining the json data structure.